# Non-existence of limit of function

Tags: analysis, limits

I was asked this question, which was given in an introductory mathematical analysis course. But somehow I am having immense trouble dealing with it:

Let $f:A \to\mathbb{R}$ be a function, $c$ be a cluster point with respect to $A$. If $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ does not exist, show that there exists $\epsilon>0$ and 2 subsequences $\{x_n\},\{y_n\}$ in $A\backslash \{c\}$ converging to $c$ such that $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\geq \epsilon$ for all $n$

It is unclear what the question meant by '$\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ does not exist', in particular whether $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=+\infty$ or $-\infty$ should be considered as the limit existing or not. A person has demonstrated to me a neat proof involving limsup and liminf if the limit is said to exist when $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=+\infty$ or $-\infty$. However my question now is, if we now say the limit does not exist when $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)=+\infty$ or $-\infty$, then how is this question proved? In fact, is the question still correct under this assumption?